# asm keyword as identifier name in C?

Tags: c, assembly, makefile, cmake, keyword

[I've seen a project](https://c9x.me/compile) which uses the `asm` keyword as variable name and the code compiles fine with the provided `Makefile` on `Linux`:

```
int
main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    struct TMap *tm;
    FILE *inf, *hf;
    char *f, *sep;
    int c, asm; // <---

    asm = Defasm;
    // ...
}
```

Here is the entire `Makefile`:

```
BIN = qbe

V = @
OBJDIR = obj

SRC      = main.c util.c parse.c cfg.c mem.c ssa.c alias.c load.c copy.c \
           fold.c live.c spill.c rega.c gas.c
AMD64SRC = amd64/targ.c amd64/sysv.c amd64/isel.c amd64/emit.c
ARM64SRC = arm64/targ.c arm64/abi.c arm64/isel.c arm64/emit.c
SRCALL   = $(SRC) $(AMD64SRC) $(ARM64SRC)

AMD64OBJ = $(AMD64SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
ARM64OBJ = $(ARM64SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
OBJ      = $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) $(AMD64OBJ) $(ARM64OBJ)

CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -g -pedantic

$(OBJDIR)/$(BIN): $(OBJ) $(OBJDIR)/timestamp
    @test -z "$(V)" || echo "ld $@"
    $(V)$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(OBJDIR)/timestamp
    @test -z "$(V)" || echo "cc $<"
    $(V)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/timestamp:
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/amd64
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/arm64
    @touch $@

$(OBJ): all.h ops.h
$(AMD64OBJ): amd64/all.h
$(ARM64OBJ): arm64/all.h
obj/main.o: config.h

config.h:
    @case `uname` in                               \
    *Darwin*)                                      \
        echo "#define Defasm Gasmacho";        \
        echo "#define Deftgt T_amd64_sysv";    \
        ;;                                     \
    *)                                             \
        echo "#define Defasm Gaself";          \
        case `uname -m` in                     \
        *aarch64*)                             \
            echo "$define Deftgt T_arm64"; \
            ;;                             \
        *)                                     \
            echo "#define Deftgt T_amd64_sysv";\
            ;;                             \
        esac                                   \
        ;;                                     \
    esac > $@

install: $(OBJDIR)/$(BIN)
    mkdir -p "$(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/bin/"
    cp $< "$(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/bin/"

uninstall:
    rm -f "$(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/bin/$(BIN)"

clean:
    rm -fr $(OBJDIR)

clean-gen: clean
    rm -f config.h

check: $(OBJDIR)/$(BIN)
    tools/test.sh all

check-arm64: $(OBJDIR)/$(BIN)
    TARGET=arm64 tools/test.sh all

src:
    @echo $(SRCALL)

80:
    @for F in $(SRCALL);                       \
    do                                         \
        awk "{                             \
            gsub(/\\t/, \"        \"); \
            if (length(\$$0) > $@)     \
                printf(\"$$F:%d: %s\\n\", NR, \$$0); \
        }" < $$F;                          \
    done

.PHONY: clean clean-gen check check-arm64 src 80 install uninstall
```

I'm wondering how to accomplish that the compiler will allow `asm` as variable name (ignoring the fact that it's bad style to do this). I tried porting the `Makefile` to a `CMakeLists.txt` but the compiler threw an error because of the invalid usage of `asm`. How to fix this without changing the code? I already forced the `C99` standard as the `Makefile` did and used the same `C` compiler flags but that didn't help:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(qbe C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -g -pedantic")

include_directories(amd64)

add_executable(qbe
        amd64/all.h
        amd64/emit.c
        amd64/isel.c
        amd64/sysv.c
        amd64/targ.c
        alias.c
        all.h
        cfg.c
        copy.c
        fold.c
        gas.c
        live.c
        load.c
        main.c
        mem.c
        ops.h
        parse.c
        rega.c
        spill.c
        ssa.c
        util.c)
```

I want to use `CMake` due to `IDE` support.

Comment: `-std=c99` should be enough for `gcc` (it works for me). What version of `gcc` are you using? And can you show the actual command line `cmake` is giving `gcc`?

Comment: From a quick test, [gcc has no problem with this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_6hH8P), while [g++ is more picky about it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WiqCgR) (maybe `asm` is a reserved keyword only in C). Probably your cmake is trying to use g++ even to compile C files? Try to see what commands it is invoking by using `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: CMake by default enables compiler extensions; you're asking for gnu99 mode, not c99. For how to turn this off and the right ways to set what version of C to use refer to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#manual:cmake-compile-features(7) and https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/C_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:C_STANDARD and https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/C_EXTENSIONS.html#prop_tgt:C_EXTENSIONS

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Your options include `-std=c99`, which selects standard C instead of GCC’s default, which would complain about `asm` in this situation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: yep, they include it, as OP included it in the flags both in Makefile and in CMakeLists.txt...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`asm` is *not* a keyword of standard C, nor a reserved identifier, though [the standard recognizes it as a common extension](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.10).  The standard furthermore remarks that

> The inclusion of any extension that may cause a strictly conforming
>   program to become invalid renders an implementation nonconforming.
>   Examples of such extensions are new keywords, extra library functions
>   declared in standard headers, or predefined macros with names that do
>   not begin with an underscore.

This is in [Annex J](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J), which is non-normative, but it merely summarizes a conclusion that can be drawn from the normative text.  Thus a conforming implementation will not reject code on the basis that it uses `asm` as an identifier.

I find that GCC, for example, accepts usage of `asm` as an identifier when any of the strict conformance modes it supports is used (`-std=c89` or `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`), but rejects it with an error by default or with GNU extensions specifically enabled (e.g. with `-std=gnu11`).  If you are using a different compiler then you will need to consult its documentation for how to obtain conformance to the standard in this area, if indeed it is possible to do so.

#### Addendum

As for why your CMake attempt is failing, the `CMAKE_C_STANDARD` property does not do what you seem to think it does.  Its tells CMake to choose, if possible, compiler options that provide the features of the specified version of the C standard, but it does not request *strict conformance* to that standard.  The docs specifically postulate it causing the `-std=gnu11` option to be used under some circumstances, and that or similar inclusive options would have an effect opposite to what you want.

Answer (score 3):

`asm` is not a standard C keyword. A conforming C compiler may not refuse compiling a program that uses `asm` as an identifier.

Choosing a standard explicitly with `-std=c99` will also remove `asm` keyword. You can continue to use `__asm__` however, since all names beginning with two underscores are always reserved by the implementation for *any* use.

---

However, it is *still* very bad style, since **C99**, C11 and C17 revisions *do* mention it as a [common extension](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#J.5.10).

Comment: @EricPostpischil but it may not refuse to compile `int main(int asm, char **argv) { }` ... at least not if it accepts `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: @EricPostpischil the standard says that the implementation shall be able to compile at least one program where *everything* there is true. The 65535 byte objects are quite tricky in MS-DOS for example... might be that the program cannot actually *do* anything since all data segment is used for that one object. It does not mean that it is good enough to just be able to compile one program.

Comment: I disagree that using `asm` as an identifier is *necessarily* "very bad style". Indeed, it can be a way to (imperfectly) enforce compiling your code with a conforming C compiler -- similar to using `int class;` to enforce using a C compiler rather than a C++ compiler. (It is IMHO unfortunate that gcc rejects `int asm;` as a syntax error in its default mode.)